# Problem with a loop in BMI calculator R language

Tags: r

I have a problem with a school task -> BMI calculator

Here is my code:

```
 #Przedziały
niedowaga <- seq(16.00, 18.40, 0.01)
norma <- seq(18.50, 24.90, 0.01)
nadwaga <- seq(25.00, 30.00, 0.01)
print(niedowaga)
print(norma)
print(nadwaga)
 #Pytanie
waga = as.integer(readline(prompt="Podaj swoją wagę: "))
wzrost = as.integer(readline(prompt="Podaj swój wzrost w cm: "))
 #Formuła
bmi <- waga/wzrost**2 * 10000
 #Zaokrąglenie BMI do jednej liczby po przecinku
bmi_round <-round(bmi, digits = 2)
 #Wyświetlenie wartości BMI po zaokrągleniu
print(bmi_round)
 #Sprawdzenie BMI w oparciu o przedziały
for(bmi_round in niedowaga) {
  if(bmi == niedowaga) {
    print("Niedowaga")
  }
}
else {
  if (bmi == norma) {
    print("Norma")
  }
}
else if (bmi == nadwaga) {
  print("Nadwaga")
}
```

I have three sequence variables, "niedowaga, norma, and nadwaga"
I calculated the BMI index.

Now I need to make a loop to check the computed BMI. "bmi_round" have to check to which sequence it fits - "niedowaga", "norma" and "nadwaga" (the first three variables) and give the output based on the computed BMI and sequence-

How can I do this?

Sorry for language in comments and in variables name - it's polish ;)

Comment: hmm... I think that this is Ok. That formula calculate BMI and first is height**2 then weight/height(after power) and in the end, multiplication and you get a correct value. As I know we are making computing since left to the right

Comment: You are right. My testing was flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is not needed for this:

```
waga = 30L #changed from readline
wzrost = 60L #changed from readline

bmi <- waga/wzrost**2 * 10000

ifelse(bmi >= 16 & bmi < 18.5, 'Niedowaga', 
       ifelse(bmi >= 18.5 & bmi < 25, 'Norma',
              ifelse(bmi >=25 & bmi <= 30, 'nadwaga', 'outside normal range')))

# or

dplyr::case_when(bmi >= 16 & bmi < 18.5 ~ 'Niedowaga',
                 bmi >= 18.5 & bmi < 25 ~ 'Norma',
                 bmi >=25 & bmi <= 30 ~ 'nadwaga',
                 TRUE ~ 'outside normal range')
```

For your loop, there are overall errors. It appears that you are trying to compare the `bmi_round` variable with everything else. Instead, your loop isn't really doing anything - `bmi_round` is changing to each element of `niedowaga` in the loop and is not being used. Here is one way to change it

```
bmi_round <- 23

for(nied in niedowaga){
  if (bmi_round == nied) print("Niedowaga")
}

for (norm in norma){
  if (bmi_round == norm) print("Norma")
}
# [1] "Norma"

for (nad in nadwaga){
  if (bmi_round == norm) print("Nadwaga")
}
```